# cakephp: Acl problem: not able to populate aros_acos table with initdb function in users controller

Tags: cakephp, acl

When I try to run app/users/initdb, I'm getting warning 512 and i'm not able to populate the aros_acos table. Does anyone know on i'm doing wrong:

```
 Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 361]Code | Context
    if ($perms == false) {
        trigger_error(__('DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node', true), E_USER_WARNING);$aro   =   Group
Group::$name = "Group"
Group::$validate = array
Group::$hasMany = array
Group::$actsAs = array
Group::$useDbConfig = "default"
Group::$useTable = "groups"
Group::$displayField = "name"
Group::$id = 7
Group::$data = array
Group::$table = "groups"
Group::$primaryKey = "id"
Group::$_schema = array
Group::$validationErrors = array
Group::$tablePrefix = ""
Group::$alias = "Group"
Group::$tableToModel = array
Group::$logTransactions = false
Group::$cacheQueries = false
Group::$belongsTo = array
Group::$hasOne = array
Group::$hasAndBelongsToMany = array
Group::$Behaviors = BehaviorCollection object
Group::$whitelist = array
Group::$cacheSources = true
Group::$findQueryType = NULL
Group::$recursive = 1
Group::$order = NULL
Group::$virtualFields = array
Group::$__associationKeys = array
Group::$__associations = array
Group::$__backAssociation = array
Group::$__insertID = NULL
Group::$__numRows = NULL
Group::$__affectedRows = NULL
Group::$_findMethods = array
Group::$User = User object
Group::$Aro = Aro object
$aco    =   "controllers"
$actions    =   "*"
$value  =   1
$perms  =   false
$permKeys   =   array(
"_create",
"_read",
"_update",
"_delete"
)
$save   =   array()DbAcl::allow() - CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 361
AclComponent::allow() - CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 106
UsersController::initdb() - APP\controllers\users_controller.php, line 82
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 83
```

The following is my users_controller.php

```
 class UsersController extends appController{
       var $name = 'Users';

function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(array('*'));
}

function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}

function login(){
}

function logout(){
}
      .........

      function initdb(){
//gets reference of Group model and modify its id to be able to specify the ARO we wanted, this is due to how AclBehavior works. AclBehavior does not set the alias field in the aros table so we must use an object reference or an array to reference the ARO we want.
    $group=& $this->User->Group; 
    //Allow admins to everything
    $group->id=7;
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers');

    //allow managers to posts and widgets
    $group->id=8;
    $this->Acl->deny($group,'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers/Posts');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets');


    //allow users to only add and edit on posts and widgets
    $group->id=9;
    $this->Acl->deny($group,'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers/Posts/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers/Posts/edit');
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers/Widgets/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group,'controllers/Widgets/edit');

    //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
    echo "all done";
    exit;
}
```

any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a record with alias 'controllers' in your acos table ?

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I found my mistake. I didn't run /app/groups/build_acl before /app/users/initdb. Since aco table is populated now, initdb successfully populated aros_acos table. Acos table has alias 'controllers'. Now everything works fine.